# How to make a Swift 2 function throw exception

Tags: swift, error-handling, try-catch, swift2

Here is my current code

```
class HelloWorld {
    func foobar() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How do I make this function throw exception when its called and something unexpected happens?

Comment: The docs are useful. You should take a look before posting a question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Swift documentation:

> Throwing Errors
>
> To indicate that a function or method can throw an error, you write
>   the throws keyword in its declaration, after its parameters. If it
>   specifies a return type, you write the throws keyword before the
>   return arrow (->). A function, method, or closure cannot throw an
>   error unless explicitly indicated.

There is a wealth of info about this topic here in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

Error's are represented using enums, so create some error you would like via an enum and then use the `throw` keyword to do it.

**example:**

```
enum MyError: ErrorType{
    case FooError
}

func foobar() throws{
   throw MyError.FooError
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First, you can create an enum that contains your errors, and implements the `ErrorType` protocol

```
enum MyError: ErrorType{
    case Null
    case DivisionByZero
}
```

Then, you can call your errors using `throw`

```
throw MyError.DivisionByZero
```

So, a division function could look like this

```
func divide(x: Int, y: Int) throws -> Float{
    if(y == 0){
        throw MyError.DivisionByZero
    }
    else{
        return x / y
    }
}
```

Comment: How to call this function with `docatch` method? For example `checkisValidIntValue(x: 10, y: 20); func checkisValidIntValue(x: Int, y: Int) throws { guard x > 0 else {throw some.Error} let value = try? divide(x: x, y: y) //... here what to do when got success value and want to throw failure value else do operation with ouptu value in this same function}`